# How do I make a transparent background with elements behind it, if possible?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm sort of interested in making a website (currently learning) and I have seen some interesting effect where you scroll the content of the page, but some elements remain static.

Kind of an effect where you scroll the webpage and one part has transparent background and you see everything behind it.

You can see such effect when you scroll to the very bottom of http://www.noip.com/.

Is it possible to do using only HTML and CSS? I assume I have to set the appropriate material background to transparent (which I don't know), and set some static elements behind it.

Speaking of my testing website, here's the idea so you can understand easier.
It looks like this;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsahZ.jpg

And I think setting that full-sized landscape picture as a static background behind all elements, and setting the background of that line to transparent would do the thing, would it?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. Where is a transparent background shown on your example page? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: You misread, it's alright. I wanted to say that the example is http://noip.com/ at the very bottom.

Comment: Also, the gray bar at the bottom is doing the same thing, you  can notice if you pay attention

Comment: You mean that the footer appears after scrolling and hides behind the other content?

Comment: OP wants a div to be revealed when the divs above it are scrolled out of the way. Bottom of the example page reveals when you scroll down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that's not setting background to transparent, revealing sections in this way called the [Parallax scrolling Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) which basically scroll layered sections or elements in different speeds or reveal elements under or over other elements while scrolling to simulate 3D, such simulation is called 2.5D sometimes.

This [**JS Fiddle**-*updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bxf7tfzg/) shows a simple way to mimic the example page in your question:

```css
html, body{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#wrapper{position:relative;}

#container {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 70vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sections, .sections2 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #EEE;
  line-height: 10vh;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.sections2 {
  padding-top:35vh;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sections h2, .sections2 h2 {
  color: white;padding: 0;text-align: center;margin: 0;
}

#one {background-color: green}
#two {background-color: orange}
#three {background-color: tomato;}
#five {background-color: navy}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="five" class="sections2">
    <h2>Section Five</h2> Chupa chups liquorice lollipop lemon drops fruitcake cake wafer. Croissant tiramisu chocolate muffin ice cream macaroon apple pie. Jelly-o toffee tootsie roll. Marzipan cheesecake powder toffee muffin. Caramels bonbon macaroon sesame snaps jelly icing.
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="sections">
      <h2>Section ONE</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="sections">
      <h2>Section TWO</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="sections">
      <h2>Section THREE</h2>
      <br>
      <br>Flavour, robusta so froth cortado foam cup acerbic, robust macchiato, single origin aged, macchiato ristretto coffee so coffee frappuccino ut strong, iced, frappuccino so et dark flavour. Frappuccino seasonal, roast latte, redeye, robusta eu caramelization
      espresso, cup, siphon strong fair trade, cinnamon body galão qui latte lungo mazagran sweet. Redeye, a cortado dark filter half and half, frappuccino a, crema ristretto decaffeinated, black milk decaffeinated viennese single origin seasonal kopi-luwak
      organic. Coffee qui shop chicory at cortado, as white beans, roast rich, filter ristretto, so mazagran trifecta black grounds black, turkish spoon barista organic aged.
      <br>Dripper, coffee whipped milk trifecta grounds, coffee whipped extra, organic, irish instant, roast, black ut strong irish and medium. Foam coffee percolator con panna macchiato, ristretto, robusta, fair trade wings flavour coffee flavour dripper
      robust americano aromatic, grinder latte, rich aroma shop crema, caramelization latte fair trade arabica ut milk café au lait rich foam caramelization flavour body strong. Pumpkin spice mocha eu as carajillo flavour, caramelization percolator latte
      plunger pot, body foam french press, milk, irish blue mountain cup sugar, robusta milk skinny, fair trade redeye foam galão roast saucer. So, viennese, cultivar shop sweet iced that so fair trade robust, siphon ristretto americano whipped spoon
      cup, at, redeye decaffeinated kopi-luwak plunger pot aromatic medium, single origin kopi-luwak variety wings sweet seasonal crema.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the trick is to have the navy colored section `div#five.section2` *behind* the `div#container` by giving it a negative value of `z-index:-1` to have it behind other elements while `div#container` has positive value of `z-index:1`.

Also giving the `div#container` a certain value of, which was 70 viewport height unit `margin-bottom:70vh`, because without this the "revealing" wouldn't happen because the `div#container` will not give us space to see `div#five` underneath it.

Parallax effect examples:

- http://www.dangersoffracking.com
- http://whiteboard.is
- http://us.rimmellondon.com
- http://poppyspend.britishlegion.org.uk
- http://www.flatvsrealism.com
- http://www.sony.com/be-moved

** Note that while simple parallax effects -*mostly stuff concerning layered sections*- could be achieved with CSS, the advanced ones need javascripting especially ones listening to mouse events as well scrolling, also you may have a look at this library [ParallaxJS](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve opacity on a div use the `opacity` css property

Check out this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cgz8kdsa/1/

Comment: Nice fiddle but this isn't what the OP is seeking. If you change your blue box to sit under the red box, and place the blue all the way at the bottom, OP wants to be able to reveal the blue box by scrolling down the page and sliding the red box out of the way.

Comment: div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 850px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:red;
    opacity: 1;
} 

div.absolute {
  z-index:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left: 10;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21; 
    background-color:blue;
}

Comment: But I don't know how to make it scroll.

Comment: I think this answers what OP asked here:

"Is it possible to do using only HTML and CSS? I assume I have to set the appropriate material background to transparent (which I don't know), and set some static elements behind it."

Comment: OP was scrabbling for a solution, but requirements are more clearly set out here" Kind of an effect where you scroll the webpage and one part has transparent background and you see everything behind it.

You can see such effect when you scroll to the very bottom of http://www.noip.com/."

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I set the background of the appropriate segment to transparent and set static html background behind all objects, creating an effect which I wanted to.

Thanks to everyone who shared their knowledge!